# navegador no me hace correctamente las instrucciones js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola estoy creando un menu responsive , pero no se que problema hay, cuando bajo a 700px quiero que esconda los enlaces y no lo hace,tengo que darle al F5 para que lo haga.

La funcion para que me salga el icono,ese me funciona perfectamente y no necesito hacer F5

Tambien me pasa que no puedo  utilizar las variables , debo poner el $() para que funcione es  por la version de jquery? Tengo la 3.5

```js
$(function(){
  
    //Menu resposive 

    var ancho =$(window).width(),
    
        enlaces =('#enlaces'),
        btnMenu = $('btn-menu'),
        icono = $('#btnMenu .icono');

        if (ancho < 700){
            $(enlaces).hide(); 
            $(icono).addClass('fa-bars');  
        }

        btnMenu.on('click',function(e){
            alert('yrs');
        });
        
        
});
```

Comment: bueno puedes mirar de usar media queries en css para el responsive o usar el evento `resize` que se ejecuta siempre que se cambian las dimensiones del navegador.

Comment: Usa `document` en lugar de `window`. Me refiero a que uses `$(document).width()`

Comment: Te faltó el `$` al declarar enlaces: `enlaces =('#enlaces')`, debería ser: `enlaces = $('#enlaces')`